# For database schedules, when determining if it's recoverable do you take into account aborts?

Tags: database, transactions, schedule

So for a schedule to be recoverable, the first transaction to write should be the first to commit, I believe.

But what if a transaction aborts? For example in the following schedule:

r1(x); r2(x); w2(x); w1(x); a2; c1;

If the second transaction had committed then this would not be recoverable, but seeing as it aborts does that mean I ignore the second transaction and therefore the schedule *is* recoverable?

When checking for serialisability you only take into account committed transactions, is this the same?

Comment: Do you have a link to what exactly "schedule" means in this context?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schedule_(computer_science)